# I am unable to load json file in my json model since the file is not in the path

Tags: sapui5

```
var oNodesJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.nav","/Nodes.json"));

sap.ui.getCore().byId("Detail--treeTable").setModel(oNodesJson);
```

I have been trying to load Nodes.json file into my json model object. But it is not getting loaded. How to get the full path of any file in sapui5

Answer (score 0):

> you can access your json file as below

```
 var oJsonFile=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/myJson.json");
```

> make sure you have json file in model folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to keep models ready is to use manifest.json. If your project structure mirrors: myproject/webapp/model/MyJSONFile.json then you can use

```
    ...
"models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "nav.splitapp.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "mymodel": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                "uri": "./model/MyJSONFile.json"
            }
        },
...
```

This will instantiate the model and set it on your Component with the alias "mymodel".

Hope this helps you.